# masstransit integration with asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I have created new **webapi** project using dotnet core.
I'm working with ubuntu 19.10 using .net core **3.1** version.

This is my proj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="6.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="MassTransit.RabbitMQ" Version="6.2.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

using masstransit documentation I have tried to configure the bus:

```
using MassTransit.AspNetCoreIntegration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace abc.api.com
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddHealthChecks();
            services.AddMvc();      


        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {

            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                // configure health checks for this bus instance
                cfg.UseHealthCheck(provider);

                cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost");

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("submit-order", ep =>
                {
                    ep.PrefetchCount = 16;
                    ep.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(2, 100));

                    ep.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(provider);
                });
            }));
        });

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();

        }
```

BUT I get error that AddBus function is not recognized 
and AddMassTransit is marked as obsolete in 
Assembly MassTransit.AspNetCoreIntegration, Version=6.2.5.0,
Following the assembly documenttion we should use AddMassTransitHostedService instead ,
but I get an error using :
        services.AddMassTransitHostedService() 
That the method is not recognized .

Is it an issue when working with netcoreapp3.1 or do I miss some packageReference?

This is be installation :

```
apt-get install dotnet-sdk-3.1
apt-get install aspnetcore-runtime-3.1
apt-get install dotnet-runtime-3.1

dotnet add package MassTransit.AspNetCore --version 6.2.4
dotnet add package MassTransit.RabbitMQ --version 6.2.4
dotnet add package MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection --version 6.2.4
```

Comment: Should work as shown, I just confirmed building on Ubuntu via Docker with 6.2.5 and it worked as expected.

Comment: You can check the [source for platform](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Platform/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Platform/MassTransitStartup.cs#L53) - it's using the same methods.

Comment: Chris Patterson - are you using aspnetcore 3.1? in the link they are using <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>

Comment: in the example you sent they have project ref to   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions of netstandard2.0 Version=3.1.3.0 BUT since i'm using aspnetcore3.1  the MassTransit.AspNetCoreIntegration.dll is using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions version 3.1.0.0

Comment: Yes, the runtime in the same project is using netcoreapp3.1 for the console application. There are plenty of other samples that do the same, for example, https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Twitch does the same.

Comment: solved - I used using MassTransit.AspNetCoreIntegration; instead of using MassTransit in Startup class

Comment: Oh, you mean the namespace?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I did it to solve:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();            
            services.AddHealthChecks();

            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbitmq-service/"), h => { });
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IPublishEndpoint>(bus);
            services.AddSingleton<ISendEndpointProvider>(bus);
            services.AddSingleton<IBus>(bus);
            services.AddSingleton<IBusControl>(bus);
```

If you wants see more, access on my github: https://github.com/alanbarros/Messtransit_RabbitMQ_Docker-Compose_DebugVsCode/blob/master/src/messages-publisher/Startup.cs